# Can't POST variables with jquery/ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xml

I have an XML file that changes every few seconds. I would like to saw the data in a div (with the help of jQuery/ajax). I manage to make data autoreload with the help of `simplexml_load_string`, but because the reload is happening only in a div, I can't use PHP commands like $_POST to keep and the old data between reloads. I would like to have a very simple example of code that takes a variable between ajax div reloads. I try this so far but it is not working.

**First try**
html file:

```
<script src="jQuery_v2.1.1.js" type="text/javascript">test</script>

<script>    
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $("#screen").load('phpcode.php')
    }, 5000);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'test.php',
        data: {'varcount': $varcount}
    });
});
</script>
<div id="screen"></div>
```

phpcode.php

```
<div>
<?php
    $varcount = $_POST['varcount'];
    $varcount += 1;
    echo  "Test ".$varcount."<br>";
?>
</div>
```

**Second try** (I tryed to convert javascript variable to PHP so that i can POST it, and then convert it again to  javascript so that i can sent it back via jquery/ajax).

test.php:

```
<script src="jQuery_v2.1.1.js" type="text/javascript">test</script>
<script>    
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $("#screen").load('phpcode.php')
    }, 5000);
    $.post("test.php", { varcount: varcount } );        
});
</script>
<div id="screen"></div>
```

phpcode.php

```
<div>
<?php
    $varcount = $_POST['varcount'];   
    $varcount += 1;
    echo  "Test ".$varcount."<br>";
?>
<script>
    var varcount = <?php echo "$varcount"; ?>    // convet it to javascript variable
</script>
</div>
```

Questions are: 
1. *What is wrong in the above code/s and I can't POST any variable?* 
2. *Because XML file is very big (120kb) and reloads every few seconds might be problem for the server, is there any better way to do it?* 
3. *I will have to POST many different array in my final code. How would be able to POST 2 different arrays?*

Thanks in advance. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to enclose `var varcount = "<?php echo "$varcount"; ?>"` with quotes.

Comment: @AdamAzad Except if `varcount` is an integer.

Comment: Its an integer (count variable). I just can't post a variable from jquery to php and return it again. I made these 2 codes to find a solution but non of them works.